# Merge [source-control], [source-repository], and [version-control]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

With [a](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-control) [few](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-repository) [questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-control) around here about version control, I think we need to pick a tag and stick with it. In the title are 3 that I could find. Which one should be the master tag?

(On a related note, do we have some kind of tag synonym system on here?)

---

### UPDATE

[Synonyms added, please upvote them so their permanent!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/version-control/synonyms)

Comment: Yes, we do. It's still completely empty. You can suggest one by going to the tag page and clicking synonyms in the box at the top of the content... (Edit: Fixed a mistake in my comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completely agree that they should be merged. I'd go with [version-control], because it can be used for more than just source code.

Comment: Done. Will manually retagging and add synonyms in an hour or so